# Use match and regex to select only digits from hash

Tags: regex, arrays, hash, match

I have an array of hashes that looks something like:

```
[#<CSV::Row name:"Eric" 1:2 2:4 3:1 4:1 5:3 6:2 7:3 8:4 9:1>, 
 #<CSV::Row name:"Sam" 1:3 2:5 3:2 4:1 5:4 6:3 7:5 8:5 9:2>, 
 #<CSV::Row name:"Jason" 1:3 2:1 3:3 4:3 5:2 6:4 7:5 8:3 9:3>, 
 #<CSV::Row name:"Adam" 1:1 2:3 3:3 4:5 5:4 6:2 7:5 8:1 9:3>, 
 #<CSV::Row name:"Faizaan" 1:7 2:12 3:6 4:2 5:7 6:8 7:14 8:21 9:2>, 
 #<CSV::Row name:"Helen" 1:3 2:4 3:1 4:2 5:3 6:2 7:4 8:1 9:2>, 
 #<CSV::Row name:"Dan" 1:2 2:3 3:4 4:2 5:4 6:3 7:2 8:5 9:1>, 
 #<CSV::Row name:"Bill" 1:3 2:4 3:3 4:5 5:6 6:2 7:2 8:3 9:3>, 
 #<CSV::Row name:"Evan" 1:2 2:6 3:2 4:3 5:5 6:4 7:3 8:4 9:3>]
```

essentially, just  a lot of key, value pairs.

I'm trying to then use:

```
choices = golf_tally.each do |match|
  match.select {|key, value| key.match(/\A\d{1,}\z/)}
end
```

Which I had hoped would select just the values for each row and put them into choices.  However, this code instead returns the same information,including the name. How can I just get the number key, value pairs using the regex and match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will grab number:number pairs preceded by spaces and followed by space or '>' char.

```
(?!\s)\d+:\d+(?!>[\s\>])
```